# Im using Vgg-Face model and keep getting this error whenever I try to run it

Tags: python-3.x, keras, keras-vggface

I keep gettin this error;

Im implementing the Vgg-Face model but keep getting this error message.

**ResourceExhaustedError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d_1" "                 f"(type Conv2D).**

Full error message

```
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 7
      4 batch_size = 12
      6 early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=patience) 
----> 7 score = race_model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), callbacks=[checkpointer, early_stop])
      8 scores.append(score)
      9 model.save_weights('trace_model_son.h5')

File c:\Users\resit\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:102, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    100     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

-I have decreased the batch size, and check the input shape but still couldnt solve it.

- I have normalized input as well.

Comment: Please always include the full error message, not just one line.

Comment: Thx for the response, I just submitted the entire error message.

Comment: Take a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62916904/failed-copying-input-tensor-from-cpu-to-gpu-in-order-to-run-gatherve-dst-tensor)

Comment: thx for the response, I have check that before i share this post.Unfortunately that post solution didnt help me :(